# How to make body background Image move scroll - right

Tags: css

I have seen one website it has body background image scrolling right and It keep scrolling right. image keep scrolling right again and again.

I want it on my website so every user will able to set there own choice background.

Just want to know if any one knows the trick

thanks :)

Comment: Read up on CSS3 keyframe Animations and Transitions.

Comment: Thanks Rishabh i will now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate background position using CSS animations.

```
body {
    background-image: url("path/to/image.png");
    /*vendor prefix*/animation: 3s slideBg infinite linear;
}
@/*vendor prefix*/keyframes slideBg {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 200px 0; /* 200px = width of background image */
    }
}
```

Demo (for webkit and firefox) at http://jsfiddle.net/Kc6Rk/

Read up on [css animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations) and [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position)